# Multi-level Listview with checkboxes - click listeners

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistadapter

I want to be able to create a multi-level listview with checkboxes both at the parent and child level.

I have been able to get a working listview using an ExpandableListAdapter, however I am having trouble creating a way for the checkboxes to communicate together.

My wish is that when a parent checkbox is selected all of the sub check boxes will become selected and when it is deselected the opposite.  Additionally if the parent checkbox is not selected and a child gets selected then the parent checkbox should become selected.

There are quite a few tutorials about a single layer of checkboxes but I have yet to find one describing  what I have stated above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my ExtendableListAdapter class :

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
private List<Boolean> _listDataBoolean; // header checkbox values
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private List<ArrayList<Boolean>> _listChildBoolean;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,
        List<Boolean> listDataBoolean,
        List<ArrayList<Boolean>> listChildBoolean) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this._listDataBoolean = listDataBoolean;
    this._listChildBoolean = listChildBoolean;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblChildCheckbox);
    chk.setChecked(_listChildBoolean.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    Boolean bool = _listDataBoolean.get(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblHeaderCheckbox);
    chk2.setChecked(bool);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: `if the parent checkbox is not selected and a child gets selected then the parent checkbox should become selected`. What should happen with the other children?

Comment: They should remain as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add OnCheckChangeListeners to the checkboxes.

Comment: Right, I understand that but I was hoping somebody would be able to help me find a way to communicate with other checkboxes within that function.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to write the following sudo code: parentOnClick(){ if checked {for all children : setUnChecked} else {for all children : setChecked} }

Comment: I am not sure how to access the children of the parent element and vice versa within the Adapter

Comment: Yes you already said that. But why not start at the beginning: add the listeners and first implement that when a user checks a checkbox and then expands or collapses or scrolls up and down the checkbox state is conserved. You should have much more items in the arrays as can fit on the screen to check it all.